# Same column edition from different scheduling jobs

Tags: java, sql, json, quartz-scheduler, iot

I have a JSON object stored on a `table > column`. Example of that JSON object is:

```
{
  a :{
    data: [1, 2, 3]
  },
  b :{
    data: [4, 5, 6]
  }
}
```

And I have the schedulers for appending values on `a.data (named scheduler A)`, and `b.data (named scheduler B)`. The schedulers are working on a fashion of getting that JSON value from `table > column` and appending the content.

Problem:

Here, `scheduler A` and `scheduler B` doesn't have any synchronization mechanism. And hence when `scheduler A` and `scheduler B` event of appending values occur at same time, `scheduler A` output will get override by `scheduler B` output or vice-versa.

What will be the mechanism to handle that synchronization? Since the JSON value will be dynamic in its behavior, I can't able to split that JSON objects on columns too, so I must should work on that JSON format.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For simplest case you can synchronize database access (for example have a dedicated object for reading/writing database, use this object in schedulers for accessing/modifying json data and synchronize on this object in schedulers).

Something like this:

**MockDB class**

```
public class MockDB {

    private JSONObject json;

    public MockDB() {
        this.json = fillJSON();
    }

    // fill JSON object with test data
    private JSONObject fillJSON() {
        JSONObject json = new JSONObject();

        JSONObject map = new JSONObject();
        map.put("data", Arrays.asList(1));
        json.put("a", map);

        map = new JSONObject();
        map.put("data", Arrays.asList(11));
        json.put("b", map);

        return json;
    }

    public JSONObject getJSON() {
        return cloneJson(json);
    }

    public void setJSON(JSONObject newJson) {
        this.json = cloneJson(newJson);
    }

    // make a deep copy of JSON object
    private JSONObject cloneJson(JSONObject jsonObj) {
        JSONObject newJson = new JSONObject();
        for(Object key : jsonObj.keySet()) {
            if (jsonObj.get(key) instanceof JSONObject) {
                newJson.put(key, cloneJson((JSONObject) jsonObj.get(key)));
            } else if (jsonObj.get(key) instanceof JSONArray) {
                newJson.put(key, ((JSONArray)jsonObj.get(key)).clone());
            } else {
                newJson.put(key, jsonObj.get(key));
            }
        }
        return newJson;
    }
}
```

**Field updater class**

```
public class ScheduledUpdater implements Runnable {

    private final MockDB database;
    private final String field;

    public ScheduledUpdater(MockDB database, String field) {
        this.database = database;
        this.field = field;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        // here we should synchronize on a whole DB access object 
        // as we need get & set to be atomic together
        JSONObject json;
        synchronized (database) {
            json = database.getJSON();

            JSONObject xData;
            xData = (JSONObject) json.get(field);
            Object obj = xData.get("data");
            List<Integer> array = new ArrayList<>((List<Integer>) obj);
            array.add(Collections.max(array) + 1); // add new item to json array
            xData.put("data", array);

            database.setJSON(json);
        }
        printValues(json);
    }

    private void printValues(JSONObject json) {
        JSONObject    ao = (JSONObject) json.get("a");
        List<Integer> ad = (List<Integer>) ao.get("data");
        JSONObject    bo = (JSONObject) json.get("b");
        List<Integer> bd = (List<Integer>) bo.get("data");
        System.out.println(String.format("a: %02d; b: %02d", Collections.max(ad), Collections.max(bd)));
    }

}
```

**Actual executor**

```
    public static void main(String [] args) throws InterruptedException {

        MockDB database = new MockDB();

        System.out.println("starting tasks\n");

        ScheduledExecutorService executor = Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(2);
        executor.scheduleAtFixedRate(new ScheduledUpdater(database, "a"), 0, 1, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        executor.scheduleAtFixedRate(new ScheduledUpdater(database, "b"), 0, 1, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

        // run test for 5 seconds
        executor.awaitTermination(5, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        executor.shutdown();

        // let all threads to stop
        Thread.sleep(250);
        System.out.println("\ntasks stopped; json: " + database.getJSON());
    }
```

PS: besides you can check synchronisation primitives from java.util.concurrent package.